# How to click on ::before element (groovy, JMeter)?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, client-side

I work on client-side in JMeter with groovy and have this situation:
[image]

To make SUBMIT button active, I just need to emulate checking this checkbox on previous step in the script.

Could you please let me know, what are the ways to point to / switch on this checkbox, using this ::before element?

Neither

//input[@class='checkbox' and @name='Information']

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='checkbox' and @name='Information']")));

WebElement checkbox_Information = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='checkbox' and @name='Information']"));

checkbox_Information.click();
```

nor

//label[@class='checkbox-label' and @for='Information']"

could help - in both cases here are error messages, for example:

Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@class='checkbox' and @name='Information'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Answer (score 0):

The chance of getting a comprehensive response will be much hire if you:

1. [Don't post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748)
2. Provide these "errors messages"
3. Show (at least partially) your code

So far if you're talking about JMeter's [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) you can try:

1. Ensuring that the checkbox is visible, not covered by popups and clickable
2. Usu an [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) to ensure that the checkbox can be interacted with
3. And if nothing helps as the last resort you can "click" the checkbox using [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), something like:

   ```
   WDS.browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("Information").click();')
   ```